# Xamarin.Droid app crash on checked "Shared runtime option"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to debug my Xamarin Forms app on android device, but my app crashes on
 start after deployment, if I check "Use shared runtime" option, to be able to use breakpoints.
if I uncheck "Use shared runtime", then app runs without any issues, but I'm unable to use breakpoints

here is my adb logs:
http://pastebin.com/vgn2jiqh

Comment: What device is it? Have you seen this; http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/50436/#Comment_50436

Comment: @GeraldVersluis yep, I took a look at this already, here is my topic on xamarin forum: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39365/xamarin-droid-app-crash-on-checked-shared-runtime-option#latest
unfortunately i got no response... :(

Comment: Ah, that _is_ you, sorry I didn't notice! :)

Comment: Can you share your app's code?

Comment: Can you add logs from the crash?

Comment: @IdoT i added my adb logs, as you can see it cannot load symbols for debug

Comment: I have no idea, since there are no errors.
It can be caused by many things, if you put a breakpoint in the mainActivity onCreate, can you hit the breakpoint?

Comment: In addition, can you reproduce this behavior over an emulator?

Comment: @Idot
since aot modules didn't load I'm unable to hit breakpoints
[Mono] AOT module 'FormsApp.Droid.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/panicbutton.com-1/lib/x86/libaot-FormsApp.Droid.dll.so" not found

it happens on every droid platform and emulator, I still have no idea why it happens

Comment: If you open a fresh new project, do you manage to hit breakpoints?

Comment: @Idot yep, I tried from sample ORM project and it works, and my solution have 5 or 7 references to different nuget and xamarin components
I tried to set propreties just as in ORM project, but it didn't helped

Comment: Well, it seems one of your references has messed up your project, try to isolate the references on the clean working project(lion in the desert perhaps:) ) until you'll catch the malfunctioned reference.

Comment: @Idot I was hoping that it won't get so far :) okay, I'll try it 5 hours later and give feedback if it helps or not, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77224/discussion-between-greag-deay-and-idot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue I do frequently see when deploying Apps in Debug configuration (use shared runtime=true) and release configuration (use shared runtime=false).

You can resolve it by removing all shared Mono components on your device by going to Settings->Apps and then remove Mono Shared Runtime etc.

After that, redeploy in the desired configuration from Xamarin Studio.

Comment: oh my god, it works, you are my savior, all these days I was debugging just by listening to words of wisdom and my heart, you really helped me a lot, now I can release my app succesfully

Comment: Could you eleborate on the etc. part of this answer? Only removing Mono Shared Runtime does not fix it for me.

Comment: I guess the etc part is the app itself and maybe the Xamarin Support libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, took me a day to figure it out. Can't believe this is still an issue 5 years later